# Update-AzureRmVmss RDP password: Changing property 'zones' is not allowed

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to update `RDP login/password` on a `Service Fabric VMSS`. I use the default script proposed here :

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mckittrick/how-to-reset-password-for-vmss-scale-set-instances/

However I have this issue when lauching the last `Update-AzureRmVmss` command (I don't try to change any `zones` parameter) :

```
Update-AzureRmVmss : Changing property 'zones' is not allowed.
ErrorCode: PropertyChangeNotAllowed
ErrorMessage: Changing property 'zones' is not allowed.
StatusCode: 409
ReasonPhrase: Conflict
OperationID : df197d60-0694-4d38-bad6-1de2163de550
At line:13 char:1
+ Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $vmssResourceGroup -Name $vmssN ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-AzureRmVmss], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Common.ComputeCloudException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Automation.UpdateAzureRmVmss
```

Any idea ?

thank you

Comment: Please check how ask good question

Comment: Hi, i have your same problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: I don't have many details but I ran across some internal training that says this is resolved by upgrading PowerShell to the latest version.